# Getting value from jquery dynamically input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I know that there is a lot of topics regarding this question, but believe me, I read all of them and none worked with me :/

Btw I use laravel-4

My form:

```
 <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
          Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
      </div>

      <div>
          <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
          <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
      </div>
```

My Js:

```
    ('#btnAdd').click(function() {

            var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

            if (newNum == 5)
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            $('#input' + num).remove();
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

            if (num-1 == 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

And on my controller: (just to check if is there anything on the var)

```
$child = Input::get('name2');
    return $child;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to return the second name only, cause the first works (cause its static, not generated by the jquery)

My question is, is there anything wrong? How can I retrieve the value from the other generated fields (up to 5) (name1 works fine[cuz static], name2,name3,name4,name5)?

Thanks in Advance, I've a whole back-end waiting for me :/.

Help me StackOverflow, you are my only hope (got the quote?) haha ;)

http://pastebin.com/VpWq0x43 (my whole view / form page)

Comment: How you post data ? Ajax or Submit.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me.  After a little refactor.  When you run it, you do see the new form inputs being generated, right?  Is the problem only that your server post is not getting the "correct" form data?

Comment: What you want exactly ? Do you want array or if want to dynamic then you have to take care of many thing and also pass additional information like max index value.

Comment: Yes, whenever I click the add another name it generates and I checked within the source-code view from browser, yes, but the thing is none, nada, 0 data is returned, not even null, like the field didn't exist in the first place :/

Comment: The browser "source-code" view will probably not get updated.  But if you run a javascript console in your browser and do a "$('.clonedInput').length" I bet you'll see the new items.

Comment: @dotnetstep I just want to get the value from them, I'm trying to solve this problem for like 4 days :/

Comment: @mrrogers acctualy is the Inspect element tool, First I create the max fields allowed (which is five) then I ran Inspect element And I see all the fields there

Comment: Try this codepen - http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/yyOjYq . It's your code (with a tiny refactor).  After I add 3 elements, I can do "inspect element" and I see them all there as expected.

Comment: http://imgur.com/EqEhtvi Check out, just SS'ed

Comment: Yes, it work like that for me too, the problem is getting their values

Comment: On my controller I tried : Input::all(), Input::get('name2). But it didn't work

Comment: Have you checked out the Network tab and looked at the data that got posted to the server?  Here's my go at it... http://imgur.com/PDZjdyB.  Notice the FormData section that has "name1" : "dd", "name2": "ff" etc.  If your formdata looks similar, then maybe you're server isn't processing stuff properly.

Comment: http://imgur.com/in6y7bb here is mine, with input::all();

Comment: See, only name1 is there, Do you think that is there anything with parent div and this kinda of #$%$? Cause I saw on other thread that the generated field weren't even inside the <form></form>. See http://pastebin.com/VpWq0x43

Comment: Is your problem with what the client is sending to the server or with what the server is returning to the client?

Comment: Sending I guess, I just want to get the values from the other generated fields and save to db, but the save part isn't the problem yet, cause I can't even get the values :/

Comment: In that case, you should probably provide an image of the Request data instead of one of the Response preview.

Comment: @76484 How should I do that?

Comment: @SylaQo: Show us an image of the Dev Tools > Header tab instead of the Dev Tools > Preview tab. Exactly as mr rogers has done above. We want to confirm that the name{x} keys are part of the Form Data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was moving my code up after my 4th or 5th input. A problem with Div's maybe?